# Kicking off mocha describes in parallel

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I want to be able to have all my describe statements in Mocha get kicked off in parallel.  Can someone help me figure out how to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Race conditions would abound since `before`/`beforeEach`/`after`/`afterEach` could be run in any order and since all of the tests are run in the same process you would have the same require cache for your singletons, same environment variables, etc. NodeJS is single threaded anyways, so I doubt you would really see a gain from doing this unless you are waiting for deferred operations (like an HTTP call) to complete.

Comment: I have about 50 different describe statements testing Rest APIs and all the tests are independent of each other.  I was trying to see if it was possible to start the execution of all my tests at once, or in batches.  I just want to be able to cut down the time taken to run the tests.

Comment: There's other tests runners (like Jasmine) that could support it, but I wouldn't do it at all. I'll take confidence and a slightly longer test run any day over my tests possibly not being truly independent and causing false negatives, or worse false positives.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't do this directly with mocha because it creates a list of it() callbacks and invokes them in order.
[mocha-parallel-tests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-parallel-tests) can do this if you're willing to move your describes into separate .js files. To convince yourself, install it somewhere and invoke it with a short --slow so it reports each time:

```
laptop:/tmp/delme$ npm install mocha-parallel-tests
laptop:/tmp/delme$ cd node_modules/mocha-parallel-tests
laptop:/tmp/delme/node_modules/mocha-parallel-tests$ ./bin/mocha-parallel-tests test/parallel/tests --timeout 10000 --slow 100
```

You will see that it ran three (very simple) tests suites in the time it took to run the longest.

If your tests don't depend on side-effects of earlier tests, you can make them all asynchronous.
A simple way to do this is to initiate the stuff that takes a while before the describe and use the regular mocha apparatus to evaluate it. Here, I create a bunch of promises which take a while to resolve and then iterate through the tests again, examining their results in a .then() function:

```js
var expect = require("chai").expect;

var SlowTests = [
  { name: "a" , time: 250 },
  { name: "b" , time: 500 },
  { name: "c" , time: 750 },
  { name: "d" , time:1000 },
  { name: "e" , time:1250 },
  { name: "f" , time:1500 }
];

SlowTests.forEach(function (test) {
  test.promise = takeAWhile(test.time);
});

describe("SlowTests", function () {
  // mocha defaults to 2s timeout. change to 5s with: this.timeout(5000);
  SlowTests.forEach(function (test) {
    it("should pass '" + test.name + "' in around "+ test.time +" mseconds.",
       function (done) {
         test.promise.then(function (res) {
           expect(res).to.be.equal(test.time);
           done();
         }).catch(function (err) {
           done(err);
         });
       });
  });
});

function takeAWhile (time) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve(time);
    }, time);
  });
}
```

(Save this as `foo.js` and invoke with `mocha foo.js`.)

**Meta** I disagree with the assertion that tests should be primarily be synchronous. before and after pragmas are easier but it's rare that one test invalidates all remaining tests. All discouraging asynchronous tests does is discourage extensive testing of network tasks.

Comment: You say "I disagree with the assertion that tests should be primarily be synchronous." Well, that's nice, but *nobody said this.* What me and other people have said is that the tests should be *sequential* but "sequential" does not mean "synchronous".  And the example code you show is not an example of having Mocha *run tests* in parallel.

Comment: Running tests asynchronously allows the engine to parallelize many slow tasks like file or network access. It is not a substitute for parallel processes if your tests themselves are compute intensive, but in most of the cases I've seen, asynchronous tests greatly reduce testing time -- quite a relief if you test before committing.

Comment: You did not address anything I said in my previous comment.

Answer (score 15):

Mocha does not support what you are trying to do out of the box. It runs tests sequentially. This has a big advantage when dealing with an unhandled exception: Mocha can be sure that it happened in the test that it is currently running. So it ascribes the exception to the current test. It is certainly possible to support parallel testing but it would complicate Mocha quite a bit.

And I tend to agree with [David's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641646/kicking-off-mocha-describes-in-parallel#comment45582948_28641646). I would not do it. At the level at which Mocha usually operates, parallelism does not seem to me particularly desirable. Where I have used test parallelism before is at the level of running end-to-end suites. For instance, run a suite against Firefox in Windows 8.1 while at the same time running the same suite against Chrome in Linux.

Comment: @Louis do you have a suggestion for handling a large number of tests with mocha? For example, we have 1900 tests and still climbing due to Ember-cli's test generation for everything scaffolded in addition to eslint, etc.

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy My largest Mocha suite has about 350 tests. So what you are talking about is not something I've had to solve with Mocha. I run into the thousand of individual tests when I run my Selenium tests, which are run with [behave](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/), which is Python-based. When I'm running tests manually, I aggressively narrow the number of tests to only the immediately relevant ones. I use [Buildbot](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/relnotes/index.html) (also Python-based) to automatically launch builds that run through the whole suite.

Answer (score 5):

Just to update this question, Mocha version 8+ now [natively supports parallel runs](https://mochajs.org/#parallel-tests). You can use the `--parallel` flag to run your tests in parallel.

> Parallel tests should work out-of-the box for many use cases. However, you must be aware of some important implications of the behavior

1 thing to note, [some reporters](https://mochajs.org/#reporter-limitations) don't currently support this execution ([mocha-junit-reporter](https://github.com/michaelleeallen/mocha-junit-reporter/issues/127) for example)

Comment: To those coming to this answer, note that it doesn't parallelize the `it` functions, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using karma to start your tests, you can use [karma-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-parallel) to split up your tests across multiple browser instances. It runs specs in different browser instances in parallel and is very simple and easy to install:

```
npm i karma-parallel
```

and then add the 'parallel' to the frameworks list in karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['parallel', 'mocha']
  });
};
```

[karma-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-parallel)

Disclosure: I am the author