# Mocha run async tests in parallel with done() callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

I'm running some asynchronous tests with Mocha, but some future tests can't be executed until previous ones are completed. For this, I can simply use `done()` callback to run them synchronously:

```
describe('first operations', function() {
    it('should do something', function(done) {
        longOperation(function(err) {
            done();
        });
    });
    it('should do something', function(done) {
        longOperation(function(err) {
            done();
        });
    });
});

describe('second operations', function() {
    it('should do something', function(done) {
        longOperation(function(err) {
            done();
        });
    });
    it('should do something', function(done) {
        longOperation(function(err) {
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Doing so though, slows down the entire operation because I'm stuck running each `it()` block synchronously. I'd like to run the inner tests asynchronously, and each describe block synchronously, but the `done()` callback doesn't seem to work that way (at least, using `async`).

Am I doing something wrong, or is that simply not supported? If not, is there a way I can get around this to accomplish my goal?

```
describe('first operations', function(done) {
    async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            it('should do something', function() {
                longOperation(function(err) {
                    callback();
                });
            });
        },
        function(callback) {
            it('should do something', function() {
                longOperation(function(err) {
                    callback();
                });
            });
        }
    ], function(err) {
        done();
    });
});

describe('second operations', function(done) {
    async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            it('should do something', function() {
                longOperation(function(err) {
                    callback();
                });
            });
        },
        function(callback) {
            it('should do something', function() {
                longOperation(function(err) {
                    callback();
                });
            });
        }
    ], function(err) {
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kicking off mocha describes in parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641646/kicking-off-mocha-describes-in-parallel)

Comment: Agreed. Not sure how I didn't see that one.

Answer (score 3):

[mocha-parallel-tests](https://github.com/mmotkina/mocha-parallel-tests) seems to have been created to fill this need. Here's a description from the project site:

> Normally tests written with mocha run sequentially. This happens so because each test suite should not depend on another. But if you are running tests which take a lot of time (for example tests with Selenium Webdriver) waiting for so much time is impossible.

I believe this will run all tests in parallel though. To limit the describe blocks to run sequentially you could put them in individual files and then run `mocha-parallel-tests` separately on these files.

Answer (score 2):

[`context.describe()`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/interfaces/bdd.js#L45) doesn't seem to be an instance of [`Runnable`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/runnable.js). [`context.it()`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/interfaces/bdd.js#L84), on the other hand seems to be creating an instance of `Runnable`. It looks like only instances of `Runnable` [receive a callback](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/runnable.js#L192).

So no, it looks like you cannot run `describe()` blocks serially while running enclosed `it()` blocks asynchronously.

Comment: Hrm, indeed. I need to do some digging to figure out how I can get this to work.

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand the performance benefit you aim to gain by doing this. Presumably, mocha is going to take the same amount of time before it returns an exit code to the invoking shell irrespective of whether you choose to run features or suites synchronously.

Comment: I need to be able to scale this to run several individual tests in parallel. In the first suite, I'm getting records from a database. In the second suite, I'm deleting records. I can't test for expected/known records if they're deleted.

Comment: Almost all test runners I've worked with (and this is by no means an exhaustive list) execute tests sequentially. For what I understand, I would recommend using a specific setup and tear down block for each feature you are testing. This makes sure that your tests don't depend on the by product of other tests. This is sort of fragile and may lead to false negatives. Also when you venture into the space of testing integrations, it is inevitable to incur some performance overhead. (contd. below)

Comment: If performance and speed of your test suite is a concern, I would recommend unit/functional testing as much as possible with stubbed out data. That way your integration tests become more like smoke tests/sanity checks and will speed up your test suite considerably. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I understand that philosophy. I can do these in series, it just potentially takes a lot longer to run. If I could split it into parallel operations, a lot of time would be saved when scaling.