# Mocha parallelism at the describe() level

Tags: parallel-processing, mocha.js

I know that I can use `mocha.parallel` to execute my `it()` tests in parallel, but how can I execute each `describe()` block in parallel while executing each `it()` test within the `describe()` block sequentially?

For example, suppose that I have a series of tests that copies a file from point A to B, then B to C, then C to D so that each test is dependent upon the last and must be executed sequentially:

```
describe('file transfer test', function () {
    it('copies file from A to B', function (done) {...});
    it('copies file from B to C', function (done) {...});
    it('copies file from C to D', function (done) {...});
});
```

Now suppose that I want to execute this test suite 3 times in parallel with 3 different files of vastly varying sizes:

```
// in parallel
describe('file transfer test 1', function () {
    it('copies file 1 from A to B', function (done) {...});
    it('copies file 1 from B to C', function (done) {...});
    it('copies file 1 from C to D', function (done) {...});
});
describe('file transfer test 2', function () {
    it('copies file 2 from A to B', function (done) {...});
    it('copies file 2 from B to C', function (done) {...});
    it('copies file 2 from C to D', function (done) {...});
});
describe('file transfer test 3', function () {
    it('copies file 3 from A to B', function (done) {...});
    it('copies file 3 from B to C', function (done) {...});
    it('copies file 3 from C to D', function (done) {...});
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kicking off mocha describes in parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641646/kicking-off-mocha-describes-in-parallel)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because that question does not specify that there are dependencies within the `describe()` (that each `it()` test depends on the last) blocks and is very lacking in detail.